# facebook like buttons strange behaviour

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

We're using fb like buttons, which worked just fine. Lately it looks like clicking on it gives no indication after it was clicked (the button looks like it wasn't clicked, counter remains 0), though the operation is posted to the user facebook timeline as it suppose to.

I've test my page with facebook linter page and the page looks just fine.
I've test it with the facebook js test page and got the exact same behavior http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/ (go to *examples* and choose the "does-like" example, then run it and you'll get an error that doesn't say nothing much).

Does anyone faced this problem lately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have same problem here so I think it might be facebook bug or their some recent changes. Clicking on like button generated with  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ gives no indication. If it is checked it won't uncheck, if it is unchecked it won't check. Facebook debug tool shows no errors or even warnings.
Button properties: Send button: unchecked, Layout Style: button_count, Show Faces: false

We use iframe code to place it on page.
Here you can find sample code we use:
http://jsfiddle.net/7nHEs/2/

I tested for XFBML instead of iframe and it seems to work. So this might be solution. On other hand I don't want change all iframe buttons that worked in previous week to XFBML in 
all my apps.

Comment: We have this problem though we're using the XFBML version

Comment: I'm now facing another strange behavior - in my local env the like button works ok (though it's not the url that defined in the fb app), but in my real site I still got the mentioned behavior.